# Getting error NU1605 when I try to add migrations (netcore 2)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.0

I have `Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web Api project` and using `EFCore 2` for working with `MySql` Database.

The problem is that when I run the command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --context "ApplicationDbContext"
```

I'm getting `Build Failed` error. I added `-v` parameter to my command to see failure details and now I see `error NU1605`:

```
error NU1605:  
    MG.WebApi (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.CommandException: Build failed.
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.Build()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute()
    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you included `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` as a `PackageReference`? If so, remove it.

Comment: Thanks @Stealth it was really helpful